# How to get the number of comments on a post

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to get the number of comments a post has, but can't find a way to do it. I have a plunk if you want to check it.

```
<div class="anuncios">
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="posts in post | orderBy:'-FechaAnuncio'">
      <div class="panel-heading" style="overflow:hidden;">
        <p><a href="#">{{posts.NombreLocal}}</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>{{posts.Anuncio}}</p>
        <hr>
        <small>{{posts.FechaAnuncio | date:'HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy'}}</small>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" style="float:right;" ng-click="showme = !showme"><span ng-hide="showme">Show Comments: {{posts.comments.length}}</span><span ng-show="showme">Hide Comments</span></button>
        <div>
          <div class="well" ng-show="showme">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment Here..." ng-model="comment.text">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" ng-click="addComment(posts, comment)">Publish!</button>
                </span>
            </div>
            <!-- /input-group -->
            <div class="cmt">
              <div class="panel" ng-repeat="comments in posts.comments">
                <p>{{comments.NombreLocal}}</p>
                <p>{{comments.FechaComentario | date:'HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy'}}</p>
                <hr>
                <p>{{comments.Comment}}</p>
                <p></p>
              </div>
              <!--FIN DE COMENTARIOS -->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/AIx0x7?p=preview

The number of comments should display next to "Show Comments:"

This is my Firebase Structure:
[Firebase structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DA4t.png)

Comment: `comments` is coming back as an `Object`, not an `array`, from your Firebase.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: @Makoto thanks for answering so quick. Im really new with angularjs and firebase so probably thats why I ended up with this. Any clue about how to solve that? just need to show the number of comments I have there as you can see.

Comment: I don't know what the structure of your Firebase looks like (and I can't directly access it), so there's very little I can say besides, "Be sure that you're bringing it back as an array if you want to access its `length` property."

Comment: Any further details should be added to your question, not here in the comments box.  There's no room for it here.

Comment: Thanks @Makoto I already edited the question and added an image with my firebase structure. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `comments` is an object, the easiest thing to do is to count the number of keys it has. You'll need to add this to your controller, or you could create your own filter.

```
app.controller('AnunciosCtrl', function($scope, $firebaseArray, $timeout) {
  ...
  $scope.sizeOf = function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj || {}).length;
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<span ng-hide="showme">Show Comments: {{ sizeOf(posts.comments) }}</span>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/l23tZh?p=preview)

Answer (score -3):

In your controller do:

```
$scope.numComments = $scope.post.comments.length;
```

In your html :

```
...>Show Comments: {{numComments}}<...
```

Comment: That doesn't fix *anything* if the length property on the comments *object* isn't an array.